# jQuery toggle slides DIV up and down, but UL content animates left to right. How can I make the content slide up and down?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jQuery toggle that slides a DIV up/down, but its content animates left to right. How can I prevent the content from animating left to right?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CqREn/6/

CSS:

```css
#myMenu ul{
    display: none;
}
#myMenu ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%; 
}
#myMenu{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(100,100,100);
}
```

JS:

```js
$("#MenuToggle").click(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#myMenu ul').toggle('slow');
});
```

HTML:

```html
<aside id="myMenu">
    <nav id="MenuTab"><a href="#" id="MenuToggle">Page Navigation</a></nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`toggle()` simply toggles the showing/hiding, but doesn't specify *how* to show/hide. Try:

```
$('#myMenu ul').slideToggle('slow');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CqREn/8/)

Comment: Oversight on my part.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had `.slidetoggle('slow', function() {` I needed to add the capital T on toggle.